# Deleting data from Firestore after a day in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I wanna how I can delete data from Firestore in time.

Like...in my method of insertion add a delete method (already have one) Future.delayed right below to after X time that to call the delete.

I already tried some forms, but no one work.

Comment: Did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/ttl?

Comment: Oh no, i was trying to do with code lmao.
Doesn't even know about this ttl, i will research to use